# Should I use data binding in my Windows Forms project?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am developing an application with Winforms, and have gone down the path of data binding my grids using a `BindingSource`. My question is:

Is this the best approach to take? Should I manually populate the cells instead of letting the `BindingSource` do it for me? Could it lead to problems further down the track? If there are any situations where data binding would create issues, that would be useful.

One of my colleagues swears black and blue NOT to use databinding. I don't really trust what he says, so any pros/cons would be valuable.

In the situation of a multi-user application connecting to a single database and editable `DataGrid`s, how would you solve concurrency issues for updating of data?

Comment: No: do not use databinding. ;-)

Comment: Databinding = fast / less control. 
No Databinding = slow / more control. (Speeds are development time)

Comment: One of the issues i have come accross is DBConcurrency exceptions: One user loads data, another user loads same data, first user updates data, second user updates data which causes DBConcurrency exception. Whats a good solution here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Swearing black and blue about *anything* without giving reasons why is, frankly, dumb.

There are scenarios where data-binding is great, and scenarios where it is more trouble than it is worth. Your colleague isn't doing you any favors if only reporting from the "pain" end of the spectrum.

For simple display of data, great! It'll save you lots of time and errors. For direct updates of data (including property logic and `IDataErrorInfo` support), again, *great*!. And indeed it is a core part of WPF etc.

There are scenarios where it isn't so helpful:

- massive data volumes (where "virtual" mode helps, or better: don't display 10 million rows; it isn't helpful to anyone)
- if you don't want the updates to be direct, but rather: deferred - although binding to a view-model (rather than your domain-model) is a good counter argument to that
- when you have lots of different threads trying to bind to the same data (again, independent view-models help here)

I would ask your colleague "why"; and if they can't give a good reason, I'd be inclined to ignore them. Without a sensible discussion behind it is just FUD.

Answer (score 5):

I personally find that using the data binding process which is much easier for programming, you don't have to do the iteration, and overall reduces LOC.

From [Data binding concepts in .NET windows forms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/databindingconcepts.aspx):

> **Advantages of DataBinding**
>
> 1. Databinding in .NET can be used to
>      write data driven applications
>      quickly. .NET data binding allows
>      you to write less code with fast
>      execution but still get the work
>      done in the best way.
> 2. .NET automatically writes a lot of databinding code for you in the background (you can see it in "Windows Generated Code" section), so the developer does not have to spend time writing code for basic databinding, but still has the flexibility of modifying any code that he would like to. We get the benefits of bound as well as unbound approach.
> 3. Control over the Databinding process by using events. This is discussed in more detail later in the article.
>
> **Disadvantages of DataBinding**
>
> 1. More optimized code can be written by using the unbound or traditional methods.
> 2. Complete flexibility can only be achieved by using the unbound approach.

Fore more clarification you should see [Data binding concepts in .NET windows forms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/databindingconcepts.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I dont see no problem with BindingSource component. Only suggestion is not to use Untyped datasets. Use BindingList with classes and your all set.

BindingSource is definitely better than traditional databinding.

You can read all about [BindingSource Component Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yy0c9z8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

One very simple example:

With Databindings its very simple to transform data from database into something useful. For eg you have a decimal column in database with means currency amount:

With databindings you can easily display it as a currency:

```
private void DecimalToCurrencyString(object sender, ConvertEventArgs cevent)
{
   // The method converts only to string type. Test this using the DesiredType.
   if(cevent.DesiredType != typeof(string)) return;

   // Use the ToString method to format the value as currency ("c").
   cevent.Value = ((decimal) cevent.Value).ToString("c");
}

private void CurrencyStringToDecimal(object sender, ConvertEventArgs cevent)
{
   // The method converts back to decimal type only. 
   if(cevent.DesiredType != typeof(decimal)) return;

   // Converts the string back to decimal using the static Parse method.
   cevent.Value = Decimal.Parse(cevent.Value.ToString(),
   NumberStyles.Currency, null);
}

private void BindControl()
{
   // Creates the binding first. The OrderAmount is a Decimal type.
   Binding b = new Binding
      ("Text", ds, "customers.custToOrders.OrderAmount");
   // Add the delegates to the event.
   b.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(DecimalToCurrencyString);
   b.Parse += new ConvertEventHandler(CurrencyStringToDecimal);
   text1.DataBindings.Add(b);
}
```

Source Link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I use the databinding because it works and that is what it is for. You can always use OnDataBinding for any customisations (if needed) in conjuction with calling Bind or DataBind methods for any control that supports them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you asked your colleague what his reason is for not using data binding? If he is against using it for a particular case, then he might be on to something but if he's against using it at all then you are right in not trusting him.

Data binding is very helpful in some cases and saves you a lot of trouble and error prone code.

e.g. suppose you are using more than one control to show your data: If you use data binding your controls will update automatically after you make changes to your data source and you don't need to write any code to update your controls in most cases. While if you don't use data binding you have to update each control manually which will result in error prone code and data consistency issues and will make code maintenance complex if the logic ever changes and complexity is something you always would like to avoid in your code.

Altogether, like most programming tools, it is where and how you plan to use it that justifies its use.

Comment: there were reasons, but pretty lame like: 'youll have concurrency issues', 'its a gotcha' and 'you wont be able to do everything you need'